# Not able to do ssh on Centos VM. Used to work earlier

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance (Centos), which I used to login without much hastle. Now, from last 2-3 days I noticed, I couldn't login.

I had ssh key configured. I also tried adding new ssh key. But, same result.
Below is the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I also tried doing ssh from browser, but no help.

Note: I'm using this server from last 3 years. And, I was able to ssh on this machine numerous number of times earlier.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Can you run SSH in verbose mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227130/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic) You will also need `tailf /var/log/auth.log` from the server itself to troubleshoot this problem.  Realize that might be difficult, but it's not possible for us to diagnose the reason you cannot connect, without information from the server on the reason the client connection was rejected.

Comment: Connect via the serial console in the Google Cloud Web GUI. Then retry your SSH command. You will see the activity of the login reported in the serial console. You can also log in via the serial console to fetch the details that @Ramhound requested.

Comment: The only way to connect via VNC or server terminal and change sshd to support password auth, after which login with password and recreate keys